# Query slow in PHP but fast in client

Tags: php, mysql

Me and our team are experiencing a strange problem with MySQL queries. We use a `SELECT` statement with a `COUNT` and for some reason it's quite 'fast' in the client we use (SQLyog), but it's realy slow when we use PHP.

We have tried to use the ancient mysql_query(), the mysqli extension and we also tried to use PDO but all didn't make a difference.

On other posts here on Stackoverflow we found that it might be a DNS issue and that it could be fixed using 'skip_name_resolve' in the my.ini but we already had this in our configuration.

**Timed results:**

Client: 2.092 sec 
PHP: 9.1071 sec

**This is the query we use:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  COUNT(m.mm_id) AS total
FROM
  db.media_multimedia m
WHERE m.cat_id IN
  (SELECT
    mc.cat_id
  FROM
    db.media_multimedia_category mc
  WHERE mc.cat_active = 1)
  AND m.mm_published = 1
  AND (
    m.mm_title LIKE "%denniy%"
    OR m.mm_text LIKE "%denniy%"
    OR m.mm_id IN
    (SELECT
      a.mm_id
    FROM
      db.`media_tag_multimedia` a
      LEFT JOIN media.`media_tag` b
        ON a.`tag_id` = b.tag_id
    WHERE b.tag_name LIKE "%denniy%")
  )
  AND m.mm_publishing_date >= "2012-04-24 00:00:00"
  AND m.mm_publishing_date <= "2013-04-24 23:59:59" ;
```

*NOTE: for this testcase we added SQL_NO_CACHE to the query to make sure we always fetch a new result set.*

We are using the following PHP and MYSQL versions:

MySQL: 5.1.61
PHP: 5.3.3

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: Please show your php code.

Comment: Can you save your query in text file and run the following code on the same machine where your PHP script is:

    `time mysql --user=user --password=pass < query.sql`
and then
    `time php -r 'new PDO("mysql:host=...;dbname=...", "user", "pass", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => file_get_contents("query.sql")));'`

and see if there is any time difference?

Comment: Can you verify that you're running SQLyog from the same machine that's hosting your PHP?  If you're connecting to your mySql server from two different hosts, that could explain _some_ difference.  Show us the PHP code?

Comment: @core1024 We are trying this now, I will get back to you.

Comment: @Sepster We run SQLyog from our local computers. I will update my post with some PHP code.

Comment: @JesperVeldhuizen and where is the PHP running from?  Where is the mySql server?

Comment: @Sepster PHP is installed on our apache webserver, we have a seperate database server (running MySQL).

Comment: Oops... I've missed the database and host parameters (`--database=... --host=...`) on the first command :)

Comment: If the database schema is MyISAM, it keeps an internal counter in the engine so it doesn't have to actually count each row. Definately a bonus with a big table. Obviously this doesn't help so much when you are filtering your results... But just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain the difference in performance, although if I had to guess I'd say one or some of the following things are in play:

- The server is optimising your query differently because of the different client connections,
- The different location of your SQLyog and PHP clients might be a factor

Like I said, just guesses.

But regardless, I've attempted to tidy up your query as follows. I wonder if this might perform better (and more consistently)?

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  COUNT(m.mm_id) AS total

FROM
  db.media_multimedia m

  INNER JOIN db.media_multimedia_category mc
  ON m.cat_id = mc.cat_id
  AND mc.cat_active = 1

  LEFT JOIN db.media_tag_multimedia a
  ON m.mm_id = a.mm_id

  INNER JOIN media.media_tag b
  ON a.tag_id = b.tag_id

WHERE 
  m.mm_published = 1
  AND 
  (
    m.mm_title LIKE "%denniy%"
    OR 
    m.mm_text LIKE "%denniy%"
    OR 
    b.tag_name LIKE "%denniy%"
  )
  AND m.mm_publishing_date >= "2012-04-24 00:00:00"
  AND m.mm_publishing_date <= "2013-04-24 23:59:59" ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The query is now fast, but it returns different/wrong results then the original query.

Comment: i think that, it should be INNER JOIN db.media_tag_multimedia, and LEFT join media.media_tag b

Comment: @JesperVeldhuizen Sorry about that.  Query corrected (I hope!).  Let me know if this works OK now.

Comment: @josephcaracuel actually, no, looking at this  while awake, I don't think that's correct; The original query OR'd, not AND'd, on m.mm_id IN (a LEFT JOIN b WHERE b) which means we can't discard rows where m.mm_id NOT IN (..), so that's a LEFT join. However, (a LEFT JOIN b WHERE b) is effectively (a INNER JOIN b ON b), resulting in m LEFT JOIN (a INNER JOIN b), so I think the above answer is now equivalentto OPs query.